Is it true that the pagans used to walk around the Kaaba as well?
If so, would that mean that we’re copying pagans?
I remember hearing a while ago about some man that twisted the abrahamic beliefs in Arabia and that’s why the pagans did this, is it true? Can anyone explain this to me?

Why the un-commented anonymous down votes?

Alhamdulillah,
Yes, it is true that the pagan Arabs used to perform tawaf (circumambulation) around the Ka'bah before the advent of Islam. However, this does not mean that Muslims are copying the pagans when performing tawaf.
The Ka'bah was originally built by Prophet Ibrahim (Abraham) and his son Ismail (peace be upon them) as a sanctified House of worship dedicated to the One True God, Allah. This is mentioned in the Quran:

"And when Abraham was raising the foundations of the House (Ka'bah) along with Ismail..." (Al Baqarah:127)

Over time, the Arabs had deviated from the pure monotheistic religion of Ibrahim and fallen into pagan idol worship. They adopted practices like tawaf from the original Abrahamic tradition, but distorted it by directing their worship towards idols and false gods.
When Islam was revealed to Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), it revived the pure monotheistic faith of Ibrahim and restored the Ka'bah to its original purpose - the worship of the One God alone. The tawaf was retained as it was a part of the Abrahamic tradition, but was now directed solely towards Allah.
As for the man who twisted Abrahamic beliefs in Arabia, you may be referring to Amr ibn Luhay, who is believed to have introduced idol worship and other pagan practices among the Arabs after traveling to Syria.
So in essence, Muslims are not copying pagan practices when doing tawaf. Rather, they are reviving the pure Abrahamic tradition of monotheism and directing all acts of worship, including tawaf, towards Allah alone, free from any idolatry or polytheism.
The pagans had distorted and corrupted these original practices, and Islam came to restore their pure, monotheistic origins as ordained by Allah.
And Allah knows best!
